# how to assign actionscript variable value to spark component in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a variable in actionscript. How can I set the label text with the variable value? I have the following code:

```
public function setObjVal(obj1:InvPrintRRTObj):void
{
    obj = obj1;
    var date:String = obj.receive_Date;
    var yy:String = date.substring(0,3);
    var mm:String = date.substring(5,6);
    var dd:String = date.substring(8,9);
}
```

I want to assign the yy value to a spark label. Please help.
The mxml code goes here

s:Label width="35" height="25" textDecoration="none" verticalAlign="middle" text="{yy}"

sorry, i was not able to format this mxml code

Comment: You should provide more details about the context. For instance, is the label defined using MXML? Is the label instance accessible to the setObjVal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is to access the label by id.

```
<s:Label 
  id="myLabel"
  width="35" 
  height="25" 
  textDecoration="none" 
  verticalAlign="middle" />
```

Then in your function

```
public function setObjVal(obj1:InvPrintRRTObj):void
{
    ...
    myLabel.text = yy;
}
```

Comment: There must be an echo in here :)

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that the label does not have access to the yy variable, since it is defined in the setObjVal method. There are two ways to fix this:

1. make the yy variable global, i.e. define it outside of the method so the label component can access it
2. add an id to the label (e.g. 'myLabel') and add a line to the setObjMethod which updates the label's text, like so:

   myLabel.text = yy; //in this case, the label should be accessible to the method